# how to know whether dealloc is getting called or not in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i am using UIviewcontroller subclasses. In my main view i have 3 buttons, each button will load a different nib. and each new nib is having one back button to come back to main view.
when i click one the back button of any view to move to the main view the dealloc of that view is not getting called? i didnt understood this.
can anyone explain when those views dealloc will be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the dealloc method hasn't been called, it means that your retained your viewController object by hands. for example, in this case dealloc will not be called after clicking back button to return

> ```
> MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
> [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
> ```

You should add

> ```
> [controller release];
> ```

to this code to be sure that your instance of viewController will be deallocated. If you are absolutely sure, that you had sent equal number of `alloc`(or any message that increases object's retainCount) and `release` messages for your object and dealloc method doesn't be called anyway, it will be more complex. I hope that this answer will help. If you will find that your situation is "more complex", post a comment, then I'll try to explain with more details.

Comment: Thank you..i fotgot to add the [controller release], now dealloc is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

I too would like to dive deeper into understanding memory management details (below surface level) where it comes to controllers being pushed on and off of the stack.  I built my framework from the text, "Beginning iPhone 3 Development" by Mark and LaMarche, but that text effectively re-uses sub-controllers and their dealloc methods never get called.

I have noticed that repeated use of a sub-controller with a NIB containing a UIWebView that calls Google's web directions url ... eventually results in a memory warning and my data is lost.  This involves repeated "reuse" of the sub-controller.

If you can point me as well to in depth text that goes into nav controller and sub view memory management, that would be excellent.